# Integration with respect to complex measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In page 129 of Rudin's real and complex analysis, it assumes that $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure and defines integration by $\int f d\mu = \int fh\ d|\mu|$, where $d\mu = h\ d|\mu|$ and $|h|=1$.

Then it claims that $\int \chi_E d\mu = \mu(E)$ is a special case, but I'm having trouble to see why $\int_E h d|\mu|$ is equal to $\mu(E)$. I tried to prove it using the definitions, but it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: but $\mu$ is a complex measure instead of a positive measure (which we know already that $\int_E d\mu=\mu(E)$) and the book just defined the integration w.r.t. complex measure as writing $d\mu$ as $h d\mu$, how do we know that $\int_E d\mu = \mu(E)$ still holds? That's what I'm confused about....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can decompose $\mu$ as $\mu_1^+-\mu_1^-+i(\mu_2^+-\mu_2^-)$, where $\mu_j^{\pm}$ are positive measures. One can see that 
$$\frac{\mathrm d\mu_1^+}{\mathrm d|\mu|}=(\Re h)^+,\frac{\mathrm d\mu_1^-}{\mathrm d|\mu|}=(\Re h)^-,\frac{\mathrm d\mu_2^+}{\mathrm d|\mu|}=(\Im h)^+,\frac{\mathrm d\mu_2^-}{\mathrm d|\mu|}=(\Im h)^-,$$
where $x^+$ denote $\max\{0,x\}$ and $x^+-x^-=x$. We thus get that 
\begin{align}
\mu(E)&=\mu_1^+(E)-\mu_2^+(E)+i(\mu_2^+(E)-\mu_2^-(E))\\
&=\int \chi_E((\Re h)^+-(\Re h)^-+i((\Im h)^+)-(\Im h)^-)\mathrm d|\mu|\\
&=\int \chi_Eh\mathrm d|\mu|.
\end{align}

Comment: Please correct me when I'm wrong: I guess that splitting argument is obsolete as the symbolic statement $d\mu=\mathrm{d}|\mu|$ already means $\mu(E)=\int_\Omega\chi_Eh\mathrm{d}|\mu|$.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that Rudin *proves(!)* on page 121 ff that:
$$\mu(E)=\int _\Omega \chi_E h\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$
Then he defines the integral on page 129:
$$\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\mu:=\int_\Omega fh\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$
As a special case of this it holds by definition and theorem that:
$$\int_\Omega\chi_E\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_\Omega\chi_Eh\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\mu(E)$$
He uses this to check that:
$$\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}(\mu+\nu)=\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\nu$$
which is a priori not clear from the definition.

Comment: Where Rudin proves the first statement you listed? I didn't find it.